# Call another function from another function C#

Tags: c#, function, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a system where my `form1` uses the drag and drop event and `form2` which displays the information of the filed dropped in `form1` . In `form2` there is a `Button` ok and cancel. Ok if the information displayed is correct it will then proceed to copy the information and make it as folder and Cancel button if its not correct.

here is how it goes:

Drop File--->(Form1)Drag and drop Events---->(Form2)Displays the information:(filename,Workorder number,bandwidth, etc)

```
public void BagsakanBin_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        WOFilenameERROHANDLER();
        Filename = Path.GetFullPath(file);
        //function para papuntahin si file kay Patching folder
        if(Filename.ToLower().Contains("pat_"))
        {
            if (!Path.HasExtension(file))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Patching Diagram Issued!");
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Filename);
                FileInfo[] FolderFile = dir.GetFiles(); //Getting Text files
                if (!dir.Exists)
                {
                    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                        "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                        + Filename);
                }
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
                // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
                if (!Directory.Exists(PATdestFile + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(PATdestFile + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file));
                }
                foreach (FileInfo filename in FolderFile)
                {
                    if (filename.Name.Contains(".pdf") || filename.Name.Contains(".xls") || filename.Name.Contains(".vsd") || filename.Name.Contains(".docx") || filename.Name.Contains(".doc") || filename.Name.Contains(".ppt"))
                    {
                        filename.CopyTo(PATdestFile + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file) + "\\" + filename.Name, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("           Cannot copy file " + filename.Name + "\n          Only .pdf,.xls,vsd,.docx,.doc,.ppt\n             Are acceptable file extensions", "WARNING!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                Directory.CreateDirectory(PATdestFile + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
                if (Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".pdf") || Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".xls") || Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".vsd") || Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".docx") || Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".doc") || Path.GetFileName(file).Contains(".ppt"))
                {
                    File.Copy(Path.GetFullPath(file), PATdestFile + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) +"\\" + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("           Cannot copy file " + Path.GetFileName(file) + "\n          Only .pdf,.xls,vsd,.docx,.doc,.ppt\n             Are acceptable file extensions", "WARNING!");
                }
            }
            PATFileNameSeparator();
            PATupdate();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see the copying and making of folder is in the `draganddrop` event
how do I call the `form2` to display information and when I click the ok button it will proceed to copying file.

```
    public void DisplayInfo(string WOfilename)
    {
        WOdisp.Text = WOfilename;
    }
```

this is where I call the information

```
    public void WOFilenameERROHANDLER() 
    {
        IssuedDisp.DisplayInfo(Path.GetFileName(WOfilename.ToString()));
    }
```

the question is how do I call the ok button on the `draganddrop` function

Comment: I don't quite understand: "how do i call the ok button on the draganddrop function" Do you want to click OK automatically in the code?

Comment: after i drag a file on my app in form1. the form2 displays the information and in form2 there is a ok button. if i press that the form2 should close and form1 will proceed to the copying of file. i dont know what to do. should i create bool and create a condition in drag and drop function like if(okbutton==1) then proceed to copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility

You could have a flag in your `form2`  like:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool OK { get; set; }
```

if OK is clicked set it to true. Subscribe in `Form1` to the `FormClosing` event of `Form2`

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.FormClosing += Form2_FormClosing;
```

then check the Flag when the `Form2` is closed and the event is fired.

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = sender as Form2;
    if (f2 != null)
    {
        if (f2.OK)
        {
            // proceed
        }
        else
        {
            // don't proceed
        }
    }
}
```

Here to elaborate a little:

**EDIT**

Here a second possibility:

You can set the `DialogResult` of the `Form2` directly in the Buttons:

```
private void OK_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

private void Cancel_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

Now you can check the `DialogResult` in `Form1` when you call it just like a messagebox:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

// ShowDialog will block the execution of further code until the window has closed 
// and it will return a DialogResult to check
if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // proceed
}
else
{
    // do not proceed
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by subscribe in form1? should i create an if statement like if(ok == true)

Comment: what is the name of your `Form2` ? I don't see the call `form2.Show();` in your posted code

Comment: @LeynadTabije glad to hear. You can check out the second variant. It is probably less confusing and less code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for Form2's button click event in Form1.

```
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    (form2.Controls.Find("btnOK", true)[0] as Button).Click += btnOK_Click;
    form2.Show();


    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CopyTheFiles();
    }
```

Comment: is that the only way sir ? i know that code but im trying some otherway.

Comment: @[Laynad Tabije] Now that I understand what you're looking for, from your comments, I've edited the answer. Is this what you need?

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the answer. but it didnt work form me. here is what i did. i have created a bool and made an if(okbutt ==true) { docopying();}. thanks sir.